# Dynamic SQL Query contains extra rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

I have a dynamic SQL Query that is providing the correct data but I have extra rows appearing, I'm not sure why.  Query is this

```
-- Nuke the temp DB if it already exists

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TBL_TEMP') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE ##TBL_TEMP

--Parameter to hold dynamically created SQL Script
declare @sqlquery as nvarchar(max)

--Parameter to hold the Pivoted Column Values
declare @pivotcolumns as nvarchar(max)

--generate list of territories that will become column names
select @pivotcolumns = coalesce(@pivotcolumns + ',','') + quotename(Territory)
from 
(SELECT DISTINCT TERRITORY FROM LiveGAPDetailedBudget 
where res_id = '160') AS X

--select @pivotcolumns

--create dynamic query with all values for pivot at runtime
set @sqlquery = 'SELECT [ProductCategory] AS "Product Category",' + @pivotcolumns +' INTO ##TBL_TEMP
FROM LiveGAPDetailedBudget
PIVOT (MAX([Budget])
FOR [Territory] IN (' + @pivotcolumns +')) AS T WHERE res_id = 160'

--select @sqlquery

--Execute Dynamic Query
EXEC sp_executesql @sqlquery 


--View results in temp table
SELECT * FROM ##TBL_TEMP order by [Product Category]
```

The output from the query is linked - I can't for the life of me get these rows consolidated to eliminate nulls....see link below

[image: Output]

Comment: If you can avoid using images and instead enter data as text it makes it much easier for people to assist.

Comment: Good to know - brand new here, still learning the ropes - thanks for the heads up.

Comment: You can't have both the correct data and extra rows can you? Which ones do you consider extra? The easiest way to debug dynamic SQL is capture the string and then run it static SQL and debug that. Take the dynamic part of out the equation. Then that becomes a [MRE].

Comment: Desired output is a single '23 SECOMEA' with 26, 29, and 75 populated.  NULL's removed - I'm looking in to adding a sub-query for the @sqlquery parameter to eliminate any other fields from the grouping.....

Comment: Do add any additional info directly to the question [edit]. If you add your sample data to the question as text, your actual results as text, and your expected results as text we will know exactly what you are trying to accomplish. And if you add the DDL/DML statements to setup the test data you will make it much easier for people to assist.

Comment: Example would be:  Product Category being '23 SECOMEA', '26' being 5000.00, '29' being 30000.00, and '75' being 10000.00 - no other '23 SECOMEA' rows other than that one.....

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting extra columns that you are not required for pivoting.

change your query to

```
set @sqlquery = 'SELECT [ProductCategory] AS "Product Category",' 
              + @pivotcolumns 
              + ' INTO ##TBL_TEMP
FROM (
       SELECT [ProductCategory], [Territory], [Budget] 
       FROM   LiveGAPDetailedBudget 
       WHERE  res_id = 160
     ) AS D 
PIVOT (MAX([Budget])
FOR [Territory] IN (' + @pivotcolumns +')) AS T '
```

Comment: Thank you so MUCH! Worked perfectly!!

Comment: Please accept this answer if it does answer your question